# Side Nav Bar Extended to Base

Tags: html, css

I know this is easy for most but it doesn't seem to want to work for me. I am trying to get the sidebar to extend all the way down the page using height: 100% but isn't working. I don't know how to do it could someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

You can find the page here: http://bcs-global.org/new/

Notice the nav bar on the side well I want that light brown color to be even with the body of content area.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the container height as 100% and you are good to go

```
html, body {
   height: 100%;
}
```

Also you are using XHTML doctype, instead use HTML5 `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Comment: Ugg... Can you tell me does html, body {} effect the body {} tag I have in my css at all?

Comment: @FrankG. Nope, it will just add height 100%, but if you declare `body {height: whatever px, em;}` than it will over ride the previous :)

Comment: Mr. Alien, I added your suggestion which worked fine but when I added j's to the body to extend it and see if the sidebar for stay even with the body it didn't. Can you tell me if I am doing something wrong? http://localhost/bcs/

Comment: @FrankG. When you use `height: 100%;` it cuts off the height after viewport, if you want to increase the height as per container, better use JS, else what you do is define a min height for your sidebar